# java.lang.NullPointerException in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I have SQL query which inserts data into Oracle row. I get NPE when I run the statement.

```
public int saveData(int result) throws SQLException, java.text.ParseException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String SqlStatement = null;

    if (ds == null) {
        throw new SQLException();
    }

    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    if (conn == null) {
        throw new SQLException();
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    /*

    CREATE TABLE USERS(
        USERID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        GROUPID INTEGER,
        SPECIALNUMBER VARCHAR2(60 ),
        USERNAME VARCHAR2(50 ),
        PASSWD VARCHAR2(50 ),
        DATETOCHANGEPASSWD DATE,
        ADDRESS VARCHAR2(60 ),
        STATEREGION VARCHAR2(50 ),
        COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50 ),
        USERSTATUS VARCHAR2(30 ),
        TELEPHONE VARCHAR2(50 ),
        DATEUSERADDED DATE,
        USEREXPIREDATE DATE,
        DATEUSERLOCKED CHAR(20 ),
        CITY VARCHAR2(50 ),
        EMAIL VARCHAR2(50 ),
        DESCRIPTION CLOB
    )
   */

    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        boolean committed = false;
        try {           
            String getTimeStampTemplateSQL = "(select (select settingvalue from globalsettings where settingname = 'DateFormat') || ' ' ||"
                                             + "(select settingvalue from globalsettings where settingname = 'TimeFormat') from dual)";

            /* insert into Oracle the default system(Linux) time */
            SqlStatement = "INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, to_timestamp(?, " 
                    + getTimeStampTemplateSQL + "), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSTIMESTAMP, to_timestamp(?, " + getTimeStampTemplateSQL +
                    "), ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);

            ps.setString(1, formMap.get("USERID"));
            ps.setString(2, formMap.get("GROUPID"));
            ps.setString(3, formMap.get("SPECIALNUMBER"));
            ps.setString(4, formMap.get("USERNAME"));
            ps.setString(5, passwdConvert(formMap.get("PASSWD")));
            ps.setString(6, formMap.get("DATETOCHANGEPASSWD").trim().length() == 0 ? null : formMap.get("DATETOCHANGEPASSWD").trim() + " " + formMap.get("HOURTOCHANGEPASSWD").trim());
            ps.setString(7, formMap.get("ADDRESS"));
            ps.setString(8, formMap.get("STATEREGION"));
            ps.setString(9, formMap.get("COUNTRY"));
            ps.setString(10, formMap.get("USERSTATUS"));

            // If the user set Account Status to Blocked insert SYSTIMESTAMP into DATEUSERLOCKED
            if ((formMap.get("USERSTATUS")!=null) && (formMap.get("USERSTATUS")).equals("Blocked")){
                formMap.put("DATEUSERLOCKED", "SYSTIMESTAMP");
            }               

            ps.setString(11, formMap.get("TELEPHONE"));
            ps.setString(12, formMap.get("USEREXPIREDATE").trim().length() == 0 ? null : formMap.get("USEREXPIREDATE").trim() + " " + formMap.get("USEREXPIREHOUR").trim());

            //ps.setString(13, formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED").trim().length() == 0 ? null : formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED"));

            ps.setString(13, ((formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED")==null) || ((formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED")!=null) && (formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED").trim().length()==0)))? null : formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED"));

            ps.setString(14, formMap.get("CITY"));
            ps.setString(15, formMap.get("EMAIL"));
            ps.setString(16, formMap.get("DESCRIPTION"));


            ps.executeUpdate();

            conn.commit();
            committed = true;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (!committed) {
                conn.rollback();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        /* Release the resources */
        ps.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    // For JGrown message
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "User " + formMap.get("USERID") + " is created!"));

    return result;
}
```

I get this error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{AddAccountController.saveData(1)}: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at com.DX_57.AC_57.AddAccount.saveData(AddAccount.java:207)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 32 more
|#]
```

Can you please help me to fix the problem? Maybe the order of the prepared statements is not correct?

P.S the problem is here:

```
ps.setString(13, formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED").trim().length() == 0 ? null : formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED"));
```

Comment: post your Class full code, if it is less code.

Answer (score 2):

(As a general rule), You may rewrite the following line to be safer:

```
if ((formMap.get("USERSTATUS")).equals("Blocked")) {
```

Supposing that `formMap != null`, it's better to write:

```
if ("Blocked".equals(formMap.get("USERSTATUS"))) {
```

In this case you are safe even if formMap does not contain the key `USERSTATUS`.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown at

```
AddAccount.java:221
```

If you can't figure out directly what this line does (it would be nice if you could post this excerpt of code from this file) then debugging the program should be your first step of finding the error (this - in fact - is a general rule).

A general comment for your posted code (which might be the root cause of the problem as well). Whenever you do `formMap.get("<key>")` you can't say for sure the `formMap` will return a `not-null` object for this `<key>`. The case that you just assigning the values returned from this map directly to the prepared statement might not be problem, but when you cascading calls to other methods of that returned object (like `equals` or `trim` may lead to the `NPE` **iff** if the object is `null`).

So consider changing calls like:

```
if ((formMap.get("USERSTATUS")).equals("Blocked")){
...
}
```

to something like:

```
if ((formMap.get("USERSTATUS")!=null) && (formMap.get("USERSTATUS")).equals("Blocked")){
...
}
```

or

```
if ("Blocked".equals(formMap.get("USERSTATUS"))){
...
}
```

and in the places you call `trim` and `length` on the resulting item from the map

**EDIT**

The cases you have with the ternary operator (`?:`) are a little more complex for checking against `null`: You need to assign null if the length of the item is 0, so this breaks down to the following logic:

> If the object returned from formMap is null OR (if the object returned
>   from formMap is NOT NULL AND it has zero length) return NULL otherwise
>   return the object itself

So this leads to the following check:

```
((formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED")==null) || ((formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED")!=null) && (formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED").trim().length()==0)))? null : formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED"));
```

Comment: I tested your code but again it's not working. I updated the post code.

Comment: Now you get a different error though ;). It seems that you pass a non-numeric value where it is expected to be numeric. Examine the data type of columns of your table and debug the input passed to the prepared statements

Comment: I've noticed a couple of things more. Your table has 17 columns and your insert statement handles 16. The handling for `USEREXPIREDATE` is missing. Moreover why the `DATEUSERADDED`, `USEREXPIREDATE` are of type date and the `DATEUSERLOCKED` is of type `char(20)`?

Answer (score 1):

The only chances for an NPE I can see are when you do

```
formMap.get(...).trim().length() ...
passwdConvert(formMap.get("PASSWD"))
```

Have you tried debugging yet?

General rule I apply on my projects is: a single statement per line - this way the line-nubers in StackTraces are way more helpful.

Comment: Your general rule sacrifices some readability (which needs to be there all the time) for some ease when looking for a problem (which, hopefully, happens at most once). Why not change the code only when you know there is a problem?...

Comment: Another rule for me is to keep methods short and refactor methods with multiple calls into methods with names that support readability way more than putting multiple methods on the same line (which for me does not seem to support readability anyway but just support a minimal-LOC-metric).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `null` like this:

```
ps.setString(13, formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED").trim().length() == 0 ? 'null' : formMap.get("DATEUSERLOCKED"));
```